# HTMLCollection is empty when form is submitted

Tags: angular

I have problems with a form that's always invalid.
Thus I type this command in this web browser to see which fields are invalid.

```js
document.getElementsByClassName('ng-invalid');
```

but the `HTMLCollection` is empty (length 0).
I don't understand why?

Here is my form:

```html
<div class="container rounded bg-white mt-5 mb-5">
    <form [formGroup]="myForm" name="myForm" autocomplete="off" novalidate (ngSubmit)="updateUserAccount(myForm.value)">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 border-right">
            <div class="d-flex flex-column align-items-center text-center p-3 py-5">
                <img class="rounded-circle mt-5" width="150px" src="https://st3.depositphotos.com/15648834/17930/v/600/depositphotos_179308454-stock-illustration-unknown-person-silhouette-glasses-profile.jpg">
                    <span class="font-weight-bold">{{user?.firstName}} {{user?.lastName}}</span>
                    <span class="text-black-50">{{user?.mail}}</span>
                    <span></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 border-right">
            <div class="p-3 py-5">
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center mb-3">
                    <h4 class="text-right color-secondary">Profile</h4>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-md-12 align-ietms-center">
                            <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" type="submit">Liste utilisateurs</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mt-2">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <app-gender name="gender" id="gender" [formGroup]="myForm" [selectedValue]="user?.gender?.description">
                            <em *ngIf="validateControl('gender') && hasError('gender', 'required')">Sélectionnez un genre</em>
                        </app-gender>      
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mt-2">
                    <div class="col-md-6"><label class="labels">Nom</label><input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="lastname" placeholder="Nom" value="{{user?.firstName}}" >
                        <em *ngIf="validateControl('lastname') && hasError('lastname', 'required')">Nom obligatoire</em>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6"><label class="labels">Prénom</label><input type="text" class="form-control"  formControlName="firstname" value="{{user?.lastName}}" placeholder="Prénom" >
                        <em *ngIf="validateControl('firstname') && hasError('firstname', 'required')">Prénom obligatoire</em>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row mt-3">
                    <div class="col-md-12 mt-2"><label class="labels">Nom d'utilisateur</label><input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="username" placeholder="Nom d'utilisateur" value="{{user?.userName}}" >
                        <em *ngIf="validateControl('username') && hasError('username', 'required')">Nom d'utiliateur obligatoire</em>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 mt-2"><label class="labels">Mail</label><input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="mail" placeholder="Mail" value="{{user?.mail}}" >
                        <em *ngIf="validateControl('mail') && hasError('mail', 'required')">Mail obligatoire</em>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 mt-2"><label class="labels">Login</label><input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="login" placeholder="Login" value="{{user?.login}}" >
                        <em *ngIf="validateControl('login') && hasError('login', 'required')">Login obligatoire</em>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 mt-2"><label class="labels">Password</label><input type="text" class="form-control" formControlName="password" placeholder="Password" value="{{user?.password}}" >
                        <em *ngIf="validateControl('password') && hasError('password', 'required')">Mot de passe obligatoire</em>
                    </div>
                   </div>
                    <div class="row mt-3">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <label class="labels">Type d'utilisateur</label>
                            <app-useraccount-type name="useraccountType" id="useraccountType" [formGroup]="myForm" [selectedValue]="user?.userAccountType?.shortDescription">
                                <em *ngIf="validateControl('useraccountType') && hasError('useraccountType', 'required')">Mot de passe obligatoire</em> 
                            </app-useraccount-type>      
                        </div>

                    </div>
                <div class="mt-5 text-center"><button class="btn btn-primary profile-button" type="submit">Sauvegarder</button></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

and the validation method which is basic for the moment:

```js
private getFormFields() {
this.myForm = new FormGroup({
      firstname: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      lastname: new FormControl('', [Validators.required]),
      mail: new FormControl(''),
      gender: new FormControl(''),
      password: new FormControl(''),
      username: new FormControl(''),
      login: new FormControl(''),
      useraccountType: new FormControl('')
    });
}
```

I also use two child components but I commented them and it seems that it's not the problem.

In fact when I submit my form, I check this:

```js
console.log(myForm.value);
```

and it's empty.

Comment: Would not recommend using the validateControl('xyz') inside the ngIf function as it'll be called a lot, on each render to be precise. And this even before the user can have a chance to type the firstname or lastname, That could be why you're having an invalid from to start with. Validity of form can be checked onChange to be lazier

Comment: If you can provide a minimum stackblitz with your missing typescript, we could help further

Comment: Thanks for your help. Here is the stackblitz link [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-r3txbz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuseraccount%2Fuseraccount-details.ts). Some classes are missing.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-x2spbc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuseraccount%2Fuseraccount-details.ts
Removed all external references and managed to get the above stackblitz running,
also made a few changes the form validity is correct i don't see any issues

Comment: Please provide all relevant code here on Stack Overflow, not just on Stackblitz. @Simplicity's_Strength Your answer won't make any sense to future visitors if that Stackblitz link is taken down or the user cannot access it.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey Made a proper answer covering the key changes, currently working on adding more relevant pieces of code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-x2spbc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuseraccount%2Fuseraccount-details.ts) forked from the comments is working as intended,
Some changes were required in the typescript code to fix the issues.

Few key points, the `updateUserAccount(myForm.value)` call was checking if the value had the key valid and not the form itself `updateUserAccount(myForm)`

```js
public myForm: FormGroup;

updateUserAccount = (myForm: FormGroup) => {
    // ...
    if (myForm.valid) {
      console.log('VALID');
    } else {
      // ...
      console.log('Is not Valid');
    }
  }
```

As stated in the comments, calling the `validateControl('xyz')` in the `*ngIf` was not needed, solely checking `hasError('xyz')` was enough.

```html
<em *ngIf="validateControl('firstname') && hasError('firstname', 'required')">
    Prénom obligatoire
</em>
```

Changed to

```html
<em *ngIf="hasError('firstname', 'required')">
   Prénom obligatoire
</em>
```

```js
hasError = (controlName: string, errorName: string) => {
    return this.myForm.controls[controlName].hasError(errorName);
};
```

Used the `updateValueAndValidity()` function of the `AsbstractControl` to check validity on click when needed, although the FormControl does it onChange already

Using `document.getElementsByClassName('ng-invalid');` native js selectors shouldn't be necessary when we can use the FormGroup.valid property directly, being cheaper to compute and easier to access from angular code

Comment: Thanks for your explanations. It seems to be ok now for the validation but now I have a 400 error with the http.put. The Api method is ok. Tested it.

Answer (score 1):

Problem is solved with the solution of Simplicity's_Strength.
Thanks for your help.